# How to create Design QR codes with Java?

Tags: java, qr-code

I would like to create Design QR codes with Java.
Design QR codes may contain a logo in form of a graphic. Here's an example for such designed codes.

[image: Design QR code examples]

How to create such QR codes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found a software that makes it possible to create such QR codes.

> There's a different way to put pictures in QR codes. Instead of
> scribbling on redundant pieces and relying on error correction to
> preserve the meaning, we can engineer the encoded values to create the
> picture in a code with no inherent errors, like these:

[image: QArt Code]

The software is developed in Go and available via https://github.com/skatiyar/qr (mirror, as Google Code went down)

The author describes it en detail under
http://research.swtch.com/qart

Alternatives are e.g. Awesome QR:
https://github.com/SumiMakito/AwesomeQRCode

Comment: It seems that the code is no longer available :-(

Comment: I updated the link. There are better alternatives, though

Comment: Interesting! Wouldn't you share such alternatives?

Comment: e.g. Awesome QR: https://github.com/SumiMakito/AwesomeQRCode

Comment: My impression is that this is doing what everyone else does ("relying on error correction to preserve the meaning"), while the solution by Russ Cox was deeply different ("engineer the encoded values to create the picture in a code with no inherent errors")

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no special algorithm needed for embedding images into a QR code. Just take a standard QR code and embed your small image into it using standard image manipulation methods. 
It may still work if the embedded image was small enough because of the redundancy in the pixel structure - therefore after manipulation you should test the modified QR code.

See also: http://contentdeveloper.com/2010/01/how-to-customize-qr-codes-with-your-brands-identity/