# How to make canvas.drawBitmap transparent?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I am trying to create an animated wallpaper.

Basically my wallpaper has some background picture, and several foreground pictures.
I want to swap between the foreground pictures with different backgrounds.

I have a Draw method that looks like this:

```
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(0);
        canvas.drawBitmap(background,0,0,null);

        canvas.drawBitmap(foreground,x,y,null);
        canvas.save();

}
```

My foreground picture is a png that has lots of transparent space.

I loaded in my foreground picture like this:

```
 foreground=decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.c1, 440,320);
```

Where the decodeSampledBitmapFromResource method was taken from the tutorial here: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

My problem is that the foreground will display white color where it should display transparent color and thus covering the background with an ugly white rectangle.

I'm wondering if anyone have any advice for me to make this transparent.
I've tried setting options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; for the BitmapFactory, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAlpha(70); // you can change number to change the transparency level
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.someDrawable);
canvas.drawBitmap(image, x, y, paint);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've actually tried this before.
The setAlpha would set the entire transparency of the image.
what I want is to keep the transparent part of the image transparent, while  the non transparent part of the image to not be transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Paint and set the mix mode to SRC_OVER

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    canvas.drawColor(0);
    canvas.drawBitmap(background,srcRect,dstRect,paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER));
    canvas.drawBitmap(foreground,srcRect2,dstRect2,paint);
    canvas.save();
}
```

See [PorterDuff.Mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html) for the various mixing options (there are many...)

Answer (score 0):

Use the **SRC_ATOP** this will put your transparent image over a background image.

```kotlin
fun overlay(bmp1: Bitmap, bmp2: Bitmap): Bitmap {
    val bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.width, bmp1.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bmOverlay)
    val paint = Paint()
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, 0f, 0f, paint)
    paint.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 0f, 0f, paint)
    return bmOverlay
}
```