# how to add logo to qr codes

Tags: java, zxing, qr-code

I am using zxing (java) to generate qr codes and want to know a method to add logo to the qr code. Is there any built in method for adding logo to it or any alternate for same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a library to create Design QR codes with Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322881/is-there-a-library-to-create-design-qr-codes-with-java)

Comment: This may be of help to you: https://aboullaite.me/generate-qrcode-with-logo-image-using-zxing/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to add an image overlay perhaps using another image library. I managed to find this resource that was able to do it. http://skrymerdev.wordpress.com/2012/09/22/qr-code-generation-with-zxing/

However I am certain you cannot add an image directly in the center of an QR code it will not allow the QR code to scan. You may be able to put a small one at the top.

[image]

Comment: No, actually the center is the safest place. The parts you definitely don't want to cover are the finder patterns at the corners, and ideally, not the version/format info regions in the image above, which are placed around them. It's also not ideal to cover the bottom-right alignment pattern.

Comment: Yeah, I was reading that word press link, and apparently there is a certain percentage you can cover?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Error_correction but this only applies to corrupting the code words, which are essentially the bits besides the regions I noted.

Comment: As the selected answer references a link that provides a resource specific to a JavaSE implementation; which would not work for Android, as there are certain JavaSE modules not available on Android. A good Android specific alternative would be to reference [Generating QR codes with Zxing](http://codeisland.org/2013/generating-qr-codes-with-zxing/); where it is explained how to perform similar image manipulations using BitMatrix and Bitmap for Android.

Comment: Can I not try to create a custom QR code with my own decoder in place, the data is all around the center logo image and I could still use the lowest level of error correction to make sure that I could encode as much data as possible? Any pointers, how to do so?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `set`, `setRegion` and `flip` methods of output `BitMatrix` to change bits in output matrix, and add any (if you have a good error correction level) monochrome image in your output code, or you can export your `BitMatrix` to mutable `Image` and do whatever you want with `Image.getGraphics()`, which gives you built-in `Graphics` object where you can draw as usual, but don't forget to increase your ERROR_CORRECTION level.