# How to generate QR code with logo inside it?

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing

I am developing the application for Android devices.
I want to generate QR code with logo inside it.

With `ZXing` I know how to generate simple QR codes like this one:
[image: Original]

But I want to generate QR code with logo inside it.
So I want to get something like this:
[image: With Logo]

Is there any way to do it?
I have no idea how to do it.
Could you help me please? May there is some ready library or example of how to do it.

Thank you!

Comment: You may want to refer to one of these questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247701/how-to-add-a-logo-to-qr-code-in-android, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296555/how-to-add-logo-to-qr-codes

Comment: http://www.qrcode-monkey.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a library to create Design QR codes with Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322881/is-there-a-library-to-create-design-qr-codes-with-java)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add your logo it as an **Image Overlay** like

```cs
public BufferedImage getQRCodeWithOverlay(BufferedImage qrcode) 
{
    BufferedImage scaledOverlay = scaleOverlay(qrcode);

    Integer deltaHeight = qrcode.getHeight() - scaledOverlay.getHeight();
    Integer deltaWidth  = qrcode.getWidth()  - scaledOverlay.getWidth();

    BufferedImage combined = new BufferedImage(qrcode.getWidth(), qrcode.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)combined.getGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(qrcode, 0, 0, null);
    g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, overlayTransparency));
    g2.drawImage(scaledOverlay, Math.round(deltaWidth/2), Math.round(deltaHeight/2), null);
    return combined;
}

private BufferedImage scaleOverlay(BufferedImage qrcode)
{
    Integer scaledWidth = Math.round(qrcode.getWidth() * overlayToQRCodeRatio);
    Integer scaledHeight = Math.round(qrcode.getHeight() * overlayToQRCodeRatio);

    BufferedImage imageBuff = new BufferedImage(scaledWidth, scaledHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics g = imageBuff.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(overlay.getScaledInstance(scaledWidth, scaledHeight, BufferedImage.SCALE_SMOOTH), 0, 0, new Color(0,0,0), null);
    g.dispose();
    return imageBuff;
}
```

Please refer this [post](https://skrymerdev.wordpress.com/2012/09/22/qr-code-generation-with-zxing/) & [github](https://github.com/skrymer/qrbuilder) for more info

Comment: How does this guarantee that the image is small enough such that there is still enough error correction information for a reader to parse it? Your image doesn't scan whatsoever on my device, while the OP's example image does so easily. -1.

Comment: How would the user be able to determine by how much to scale it? A real solution to this is aware of the exact error correction information in a QR code and how it is laid out, and uses that to determine a feasibly-scannable overlay size.

Comment: I think, OP's requirement was to embed his logo, may be as a transparent overlay image, which doesn't affect the readability of QR code. the ratio to which the logo is scaled was not a specification to the question. And I just tried to help him with the method helped me earlier. Thanks for raising this concern, will surely update it with a perfect solution.

Comment: Where is logo? I mean where we are giving logo image?

Answer (score 3):

In **Kotlin** with zxing library and overlay from assets folder.

- The correction needs to be made because the overlay will hide some part of the QR Code;
- Class MatrixToImageWriter is from: https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen

  ```
  private fun generateQrCodeWithOverlay(qrCodeData: String): Bitmap? {

     val hints = HashMap<EncodeHintType?, Any?>()
     // The Error Correction level H provide a QR Code that can be covered by 30%
     hints[EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION] = ErrorCorrectionLevel.H

     val writer = QRCodeWriter()

     return try {
         // Create a QR Code from qrCodeData and 512 by 512 pixels, same size as my Logo
         val encodedQrCode = writer.encode(qrCodeData, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 512, 512, hints)

         var qrCodeBitmap: Bitmap = MatrixToImageWriter.toBitmap(encodedQrCode)

         val qrCodeCanvas = Canvas(qrCodeBitmap)

         // Used to resize the image
         val scaleFactor = 4

         val logo =
           BitmapFactory.decodeStream(app.assets.open("path/to/your/logo.png"))

         // Resizing the logo increasing the density to keep it sharp
         logo.density = logo.density * scaleFactor

         val xLogo = (512 - logo.width / scaleFactor) / 2f
         val yLogo = (512 - logo.height / scaleFactor) / 2f

         qrCodeCanvas.drawBitmap(logo, xLogo, yLogo, null)

         qrCodeBitmap
     } catch (e: Exception) {
         // handle errors
         null
     }
  }
  ```

Comment: I import the library but don't found "EncodeHintType" "QRCodeWriter" and "ErrorCorrectionLevel"

Comment: Did you import the two libraries, zxing and QRGen? Because [EncodeHintType](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/EncodeHintType.java), [QRCodeWriter](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/qrcode/QRCodeWriter.java) and [ErrorCorrectionLevel](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/qrcode/decoder/ErrorCorrectionLevel.java) belongs to zxing library.

Answer (score 0):

I created the following Kotlin Extention, which adds a Bitmap to the centre of another Bitmap:

```
fun Bitmap.addOverlayToCenter(overlayBitmap: Bitmap): Bitmap {

    val bitmap2Width = overlayBitmap.width
    val bitmap2Height = overlayBitmap.height
    val marginLeft = (this.width * 0.5 - bitmap2Width * 0.5).toFloat()
    val marginTop = (this.height * 0.5 - bitmap2Height * 0.5).toFloat()
    val canvas = Canvas(this)
    canvas.drawBitmap(this, Matrix(), null)
    canvas.drawBitmap(overlayBitmap, marginLeft, marginTop, null)
    return this
}
```

Can find [my full solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54628972/how-to-generate-qr-code-with-image-overlay-in-gluon/59096327#59096327).

Comment: Yes, if you set hashMapOf(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION to ErrorCorrectionLevel.H), check out the "my full solution here" link for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to try out my library, which provides a lot of different qr code styles and convenient options to add a logo either as Image or Base64 String.

You can check it out here: https://github.com/SimonScholz/qr-code-with-logo or directly on maven cental: https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/io.github.simonscholz/qr-code-with-logo

Within the readme you find a lot of examples and the repository consists of examples for Java and Kotlin.

I even created a small Swing desktop application to create qr code, which can also generate code for you.

Currently I am also working on supporting SVG images.

Answer (score -1):

There is plenty online QR code generator, such as https://app.aotol.com/qr/api

You can just reference the QR image url to it such as

```
<img src="https://app.aotol.com/qr/api?qr_content=https://wwww.google.com&qr_logo=https://blog.hubspot.com/hubfs/image8-2.jpg">
```