# how to generate qrcode empty center?

Tags: java, android, zxing

I am generate qrCode using zxing.
Ordinary QR codes can be created, but I want to create QR codes that are empty in the center or contain LOGO in the center.
Can we create a QR code that recognizes well regardless of the size of LOGO?
I want to like this image

[image]

Comment: Tried https://github.com/SumiMakito/AwesomeQRCode ?

Comment: implementation 'com.github.SumiMakito:AwesomeQRCode:1.1.0'
is right??????

Comment: `implementation 'com.github.SumiMakito:AwesomeQRCode:1.2.0'`

Comment: Thank you!! I'm Success generate QrCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [this](http://github.com/SumiMakito/AwesomeQRCode) library. ( SumiMakito /
AwesomeQRCode
)

Comment: You are so Kind!!! Thank you!!
I'm succeesss!!

Comment: Thank You bro . Kindly mark my answer as correct answer.

Comment: Sorry to late... But Now I'm marking your answer is correct answer

Comment: @Juro Kindly up vote the answer as it may help someone else in future.

Comment: @KamalNayan Can we do same using itext library?

Comment: @SachinJ do you need to print qr code on a pdf?

Comment: @KamalNayan yes. Zxing is not allowed in organisation due to security reason . so i have created QR using itext. but struggling to add logo into it.

Comment: my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73475967/using-itext-how-to-add-logo-into-qr-code

Comment: @SachinJ have you tried canvas to draw logo on the generated qr code ?

Comment: @KamalNayan No. Can you give me link or reference to check?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35104430/14187529