# Using itext How to add Logo into QR code?

Tags: java, itext, zxing, itext7

Note : I can not use zxing library because its restricted in my organization.

I knew using itext we can create QR code but struggling to add Logo in it as shown in below image

```
 BarcodeQRCode qrcode = new BarcodeQRCode(myString.trim(), 1, 1, null);
 Image qrcodeImage = qrcode.getImage();
 qrcodeImage.setAbsolutePosition(10,500);
 qrcodeImage.scalePercent(200);
 doc.add(qrcodeImage);
```

[image]

Comment: If your org can use itext (which needs commercial license) then you can convince them to have zxing (apache License) since itext codes are mostly similar from zxing

Comment: @shihabudheenk yes we raised deviation request to security team but as of now at org level zxing is not approved yet. Hopefully they will approve in future. Thanks for comment.